# Update Sass (SCSS) variables programmatically from React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, scss-mixins

This is a [valid sass code](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables).

```
$dark-theme: true !default;
$primary-color: #f8bbd0 !default;
$accent-color: #6a1b9a !default;

@if $dark-theme {
  $primary-color: darken($primary-color, 60%);
  $accent-color: lighten($accent-color, 60%);
}

.button {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  border: 1px solid $accent-color;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

So, it is possible to change variables based upon conditions. But, how do we update these variables from the frontend? I want to change the value of $dark-theme to false on a press of a button in the frontend? Is it possible to do so? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible to change the sass, but you can do it like this

```
html {
  --lightBtn: #FE016C;
  --lightBg: #fff;
  --lightColor: #232323;
}

html[data-theme='dark'] {
   background: var(--lightBg);
  --lightBtn: #FFBD07;
  --lightBg: #232323;
  --lightColor: #fff;
}
```

And the button will toggle the attribute

```
        buttonElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.checked) {
                trans()
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
            } else {
                trans()
                document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
            }
        })
```

other Selector

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--lightColor); 
}
```

`color` will change according to `data-theme`

credit: https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/MdvWmg

Comment: Thanks. Will try this.